# How to make a constructor that takes a String and stores the value in a variable?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to Java and for my assignment I've been asked to create an instance variable of type String called words. Then I must next "Has a constructor which takes a String. This is converted into lower case and stored in words. Use a method from the String API to make the string lower case." Is this how it would be done or is there a different way:

```
public class WordGroup {
    //Constructor should be converted to lowercase and put values in string variable "words".
    String x;
    String words = new String (x.toLowerCase());


} 
}
```

I know it's a simple question but it may also help other beginners like me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your above example, `words` would lose its reference as soon as the constructor was done being called, and would be gone forever. You need to create a variable in the scope of the object, not the scope of the method.

As simple as they come

```
public class Grouping {

    private final String words;

    public Grouping( String input ) {

        words = input.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getWords() {

        return words;
    }
}
```

Then from your caller class

```
Grouping grouping = new Grouping("These Are Some Words");
System.out.println( grouping.getWords() );
```

Yields

> these are some words

Answer (score 0):

In your class, have an instance variable that will hold your string object.
Now, write a constructor that takes a string argument. Within the constructor, we use a built-in method from the `String` class to set the string variable in lower case.

Sample program:

```
public class WordGroup {

String myStr;

public WordGroup(String aString) {
    this.myStr = aString.toLowerCase();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WordGroup h = new WordGroup("ALLCAPS");

    System.out.println(h.myStr);
}
}
```

I highly recommend reading about constructors [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful and I will visit the link now.